# How a SIP end user device find address of registrar server?

Tags: sip

Can somebody please explain that How a SIP end user device find address of registrar server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it doesn't have to search for anything, it's just part of the configuration. It performs DNS or DNS SRV resolution at most.

Optionally there are many autoprovisioning techniques, based on DNS option 66, multicast SUBSCRIBE or some fixed server provided by the manufacturer.